# How to check password in bash

Tags: bash, pam

Is it possible to check that user password is correct in bash script? If so please show me how. Thank you

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/how-to-check-password-with-linux

Comment: unclear question, you need to compare it to the system password or to a password in another system ?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
#ensure sudo isn't saving a recent password
sudo -k

#prime it
echo $ROOTPASSWORD | sudo -S echo hello &> /dev/null

#test it
if ! [ "$(sudo -n echo hello 2>&1)" == "hello" ]; then
    echo "Incorrect password was entered"
fi
```